# Why is my server failing to parse this JSON code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, parsing

I had some JSON code (since lost) that my server parsed successfully. I kept the structure and just added/altered some data entries. Now my code is returning the following error when I try to parse it:

```
JSON::ParserError in Static#testing4
Showing /home/user/website/app/views/static/testing4.html.erb where line #44 raised:

399: unexpected token at '  {
        "title": "TITLE1",
        "capital": "Rome",
        "length": 2.7,
        "date": "2017-1-2",
        "tags": [
          "Culture"
        ]
    }],
    "2": [
      {
        "title": "TITLE2",
        "capital": "Paris",
        "age": 1.2,
        "date": "2017-2-1",
        "tags": [
          "Culture"
        ]
    }]
}
'
```

Here's my code. **The problem is that the `{"1":[` at the beginning isn't being parsed for some reason.** There is no associated controller action for this view.

```
<!--testing4.html.erb-->
<%
require 'json'
require 'pp'

json = <<END_OF_JSON
{
    "1": [
      {
        "title": "TITLE1",
        "capital": "Rome",
        "length": 2.7,
        "date": "2017-1-2",
        "tags": [
          "Culture"
        ]
    }],
    "2": [
      {
        "title": "TITLE2",
        "capital": "Paris",
        "age": 1.2,
        "date": "2017-2-1",
        "tags": [
          "Culture"
        ]
    }]
}
END_OF_JSON


%>
<%= obj = JSON.parse(json) %>
```

---

**Trying to output it without parsing it has the following result:**

```
<%
require 'json'
require 'pp'

json = <<END_OF_JSON
{
    "1": [
      {
        "title": "TITLE1",
        "capital": "Rome",
        "length": 2.7,
        "date": "2017-1-2",
        "tags": [
          "Culture"
        ]
    }],
    "2": [
      {
        "title": "TITLE2",
        "capital": "Paris",
        "age": 1.2,
        "date": "2017-2-1",
        "tags": [
          "Culture"
        ]
    }]
}
END_OF_JSON


%>
PUTS: <%= puts json %><br>
PP: <%= pp json %>


---output---

PUTS: 
PP: { "1": [   {     "title": "TITLE1",     "capital": "Rome",     "length": 2.7,     "date": "2017-1-2",     "tags": [       "Culture"     ] }], "2": [   {     "title": "TITLE2",     "capital": "Paris",     "age": 1.2,     "date": "2017-2-1",     "tags": [       "Culture"     ] }] }
```

Comment: Your code for parsing the JSON is correct. If you put the JSON in as a string, does it still throw the error? Check that it's saving correctly in the *file.json* file. Try removing the spacing from the json and see if that makes a difference too

Comment: @CynePhoba12 Wait, how would I put the JSON in as a string? Just put quotes around it? Also, by removing spacing, do you mean write the whole thing on one line?

Comment: Yeah. Try using a website such as http://www.httputility.net/json-minifier.aspx to remove the extra line breaks, and then wrap it in single quotes.

Comment: I'm not sure why your parser is wrapped inside ERB tags. Also, short form: `JSON.parse(File.open('file.json'))` works *if* the file has valid content.

Comment: @tadman It's because I'm working within an html.erb document.

Comment: Normally it's best to keep the code in your ERB files to a minimum and offload anything heavy to a helper method or by doing some preparation in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is jsonlint unreliable, or is something else going on?

jsonlint is reliable, and ruby has no trouble parsing the json you posted:

```
require 'json'
require 'pp' 

json = <<END_OF_JSON
{  
    "1": [
      {
        "title": "TITLE1",
        "capital": "Rome",
        "length": 2.7,
        "date": "2017-1-2",
        "tags": [
          "Culture"
        ]
    }],
    "2": [
      {
        "title": "TITLE2",
        "capital": "Paris",
        "age": 1.2,
        "date": "2017-2-1",
        "tags": [
          "Culture"
        ]
    }]
}
END_OF_JSON

obj = JSON.parse(json)
pp obj

--output:--

{"1"=>
  [{"title"=>"TITLE1",
    "capital"=>"Rome",
    "length"=>2.7,
    "date"=>"2017-1-2",
    "tags"=>["Culture"]}],
 "2"=>
  [{"title"=>"TITLE2",
    "capital"=>"Paris",
    "age"=>1.2,
    "date"=>"2017-2-1",
    "tags"=>["Culture"]}]}
```

However, non-printing characters won't necessarily be visible if you look at a file or output a string:

```
test = "\001hello"
puts test
p test
    
--output:--
hello
"\u0001hello"
```

You'll get a parse error here:

```
require 'json'
require 'pp' 

json = <<END_OF_JSON
{
    \001"1": [1, 2, 3]
}
END_OF_JSON

obj = JSON.parse(json)
```

Even though the json looks fine when you output it:

```
require 'json'
require 'pp' 

json = <<END_OF_JSON
{
    \001"1": [1, 2, 3]
}
END_OF_JSON

puts json
obj = JSON.parse(json)

--output:--
{
    "1": [1, 2, 3]
}

/Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse': 784: unexpected token at '{ (JSON::ParserError)
    "1": [1, 2, 3]
}
'
    from /Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
    from 1.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

So you may want to read in your json from the file, then use `p` to output the text, then examine the text for any strange characters.

Also, please copy and paste your full error message--don't ever type out what you think an error message says, then claim that is what your program produced. I can sort of duplicate the error message you posted with this json:

```
json = <<END_OF_JSON
(code) = {
    "1": [
      {
        "title": "TITLE1",
        "capital": "Rome",
        "length": 2.7,
        "date": "2017-1-2",
        "tags": [
          "Culture"
        ]
    }],
    "2": [
      {
        "title": "TITLE2",
        "capital": "Paris",
        "age": 1.2,
        "date": "2017-2-1",
        "tags": [
          "Culture"
        ]
    }]
}
END_OF_JSON

obj = JSON.parse(json)

--output:--
`parse': 784: unexpected token at '(code) = { (JSON::ParserError)
    "1": [
      {
        "title": "TITLE1",
        "capital": "Rome",
        "length": 2.7,
        "date": "2017-1-2",
        "tags": [
          "Culture"
        ]
    }],
    "2": [
      {
        "title": "TITLE2",
        "capital": "Paris",
        "age": 1.2,
        "date": "2017-2-1",
        "tags": [
          "Culture"
        ]
    }]
}
'
    from /Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
    from 1.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

**Response to comment 1**:

The error message contains the json that rails is seeing, and here it is:

```
399: unexpected token at '  {   #<===Opening brace, which starts a javascript object.
        "title": "TITLE1",
        "capital": "Rome",
        "length": 2.7,
        "date": "2017-1-2",
        "tags": [
          "Culture"
        ]
    }],   #<====First, a closing brace that ends the javascript object, followed by a closing bracket, ending what?
    "2": [
      {
        "title": "TITLE2",
        "capital": "Paris",
        "age": 1.2,
        "date": "2017-2-1",
        "tags": [
          "Culture"
        ] 
    }]
}
```

If I put that invalid json in a rails view:

```
<%
json = <<END_OF_JSON 
{
        "title": "TITLE1",
        "capital": "Rome",
        "length": 2.7,
        "date": "2017-1-2",
        "tags": [
          "Culture"
        ]
    }],
    "2": [
      {
        "title": "TITLE2",
        "capital": "Paris",
        "age": 1.2,
        "date": "2017-2-1",
        "tags": [
          "Culture"
        ]
    }]
}
END_OF_JSON

obj = JSON.parse(json)
%>
```

...then enter the route in my browser that will display that view, here is the error message I get in my browser:

```
Showing /Users/7stud/rails_projects/test4/app/views/users/index.html.erb where line #27 raised:

784: unexpected token at '{
        "title": "TITLE1",
        "capital": "Rome",
        "length": 2.7,
        "date": "2017-1-2",
        "tags": [
          "Culture"
        ]
    }],
    "2": [
      {
        "title": "TITLE2",
        "capital": "Paris",
        "age": 1.2,
        "date": "2017-2-1",
        "tags": [
          "Culture"
        ]
    }]
}
'
```

Look familiar?  If instead you had an error elsewhere in your json, like here:

```
<%
json = <<END_OF_JSON
{    
  "1": [
      {
        "title": "TITLE1",
        "capital": "Rome",
        "length": 2.7,
        "date": "2017-1-2",
        "tags": [
          "Culture"
        ]
      }
  ],
  "2":   #<====Missing opening bracket
    {
        "title": "TITLE2",
        "capital": "Paris",
        "age": 1.2,
        "date": "2017-2-1",
        "tags": [
          "Culture"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
END_OF_JSON

obj = JSON.parse(json)
%>
```

Then you would see an error message like the following in your browser:

```
Showing /Users/7stud/rails_projects/test4/app/views/users/index.html.erb where line #32 raised:

784: unexpected token at '{    
  "1": [   #<===Note the presence of "1": [, unlike in your error message.
      {
        "title": "TITLE1",
        "capital": "Rome",
        "length": 2.7,
        "date": "2017-1-2",
        "tags": [
          "Culture"
        ]
      }
  ],
  "2":    
    {
        "title": "TITLE2",
        "capital": "Paris",
        "age": 1.2,
        "date": "2017-2-1",
        "tags": [
          "Culture"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
'
```

Therefore, the `"1": [` is not present in the json that rails sees.  If you need more help, you need to copy and paste the code for:

1. Your controller and the action.
2. The view for the action.

**Response to comment 2**:

A rails view is able to render the following json without error (all whitespace removed):

```
<!--testing4.html.erb-->
<%
require 'json'
require 'pp'

json = <<END_OF_JSON
{
  "1": [{"title": "TITLE1", "capital": "Rome", "length": 2.7, "date": "2017-1-2", "tags": ["Culture"]}],
  "2": [{"title": "TITLE2", "capital": "Paris", "age": 1.2, "date": "2017-2-1", "tags": ["Culture"]}]
}
END_OF_JSON

%>
<%= obj = JSON.parse(json) %>
```

And, a rails view is able to render the following json without error (all whitespace added back in):

```
<!--testing4.html.erb-->
<%
require 'json'
require 'pp'

json = <<END_OF_JSON
{
     "1": [
       {
         "title": "TITLE1", 
         "capital": "Rome", 
         "length": 2.7, 
         "date": "2017-1-2", 
         "tags": [
           "Culture"
         ]
     }],
     "2": [
       {
         "title": "TITLE2", 
         "capital": "Paris", 
         "age": 1.2, "date": 
         "2017-2-1", 
         "tags": [
           "Culture"
         ]
     }]
}
END_OF_JSON

%>
<%= obj = JSON.parse(json) %>
```

However, for some reason a rails view cannot render your json:

```
<!--testing4.html.erb-->
<%
require 'json'
require 'pp'

json = <<END_OF_JSON
{
    "1": [
      {
        "title": "TITLE1",
        "capital": "Rome",
        "length": 2.7,
        "date": "2017-1-2",
        "tags": [
          "Culture"
        ]
    }],
    "2": [
      {
        "title": "TITLE2",
        "capital": "Paris",
        "age": 1.2,
        "date": "2017-2-1",
        "tags": [
          "Culture"
        ]
    }]
}
END_OF_JSON


%>
<%= obj = JSON.parse(json) %>
```

After some further investigation, your json has a mixture of ascii spaces (20 in hex notation) and a type of UTF-8 space character called an `EM SPACE` (`U+2003`, `e2 80 83` in UTF-8).  The first `EM SPACE` in your json occurs here:

```
{
    "1": [
      {
    ^
    |
 Right there
```

...which coincidentally is where the rails error message is cutting off your json.  Immediately preceding that opening brace (`7b` in hex notation) is an ascii space(`20` in hex notation), and the character preceding the ascii space is a three byte UTF-8 character called an `EM SPACE`(U+2003, `e2 80 83` in UTF-8).  Characters encoded in the UTF-8 encoding are supposed to be legal json.  jsonlint accepts the `EM SPACE`, but rails chokes on it.

As a short example of the problem, the following javascript array has an `EM SPACE` after each comma:

```
<!--testing4.html.erb-->  
<%
json = "[1, 2, 3]"
%>

<%= obj = JSON.parse(json) %>
```

Here's the error in my browser:

```
419: unexpected token at ' 2, 3]'
```

The rails error chops off the json up to the first `EM SPACE`.

It turns out that while UTF-8 characters are allowed in json, there are only a few ascii white space characters that are allowed between json terms--not just any UTF-8 character.  See [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-2).  Using an `EM SPACE` between json terms is conceptually equivalent to using, say, a `z` between terms.  As a result, the json containing the `EM SPACE` characters is illegal json.  It would be legal to use an `EM SPACE` inside a string, but not between json terms.

The following jsonlinter reports that the json with the EM SPACE characters is invalid:

http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html

It appears that some jsonlinters are more reliable than others.

**A solution:**

You can use `gsub()` to replace all the `EM SPACE` characters with ascii spaces:

```
...
...
END_OF_JSON

clean_json = json.gsub("\u2003", ' ')

%>
<%= obj = JSON.parse(clean_json) %>
```

If you got that json from a service somewhere, you should shoot them an email and let them know that the json they are sending out is illegal.

Comment: I added the full error message. I also printed the json without parsing, and to my eyes it printed exactly what it should have, with no special or unusual characters.

Comment: @JoeMorano,  The json that rails is seeing is invalid.  See the bottom of my answer.

Comment: You're absolutely right that `{"1":[` is the problem, but I can't imagine why it isn't being parsed -- I swear yesterday I had different JSON with this exact format that worked. Anyway, I added my full view. There is no associated controller action; the route points straight to the html.erb file.

Comment: @JoeMorano, After deleting all the whitespace in your json, then adding back the whitespace, your json renders fine for me.  See the bottom of my answer.

Comment: By the way, you don't `require json` in rails.

Comment: Wow, that's crazy. Awesome job figuring that out!